# Recommended architecture for an application which syncs with server

Tags: architecture, client-server

I am making an application, which syncs the data-entered locally, with the server.

Challenges
 1. The application **should never stop accepting data**
 2. **Internet connectivity is intermittent** (which means that when internet connection is not there it keep collecting data offline, and should sync when internet becomes available)
 3. **Strong security**. Once the data has been entered by the user, there should be no way to delete it. (obviously, when the data reaches server its safe. When its there only locally, then it should be very safe!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up choosing, Node-Webkit (it uses embedded chrome browser), which solves all the purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions that need to be answered before a suggestion can be made here.

1)  What system are you using to enter data locally?  Is this a database driven app?  Are you talking about local files?  What kind of infrastructure is available on the local computer?  What OS is the local computer using?  What kind of platform is this running on (web, thick client, win32, java, etc).

2)  What do you mean by "Strong Security".  Do you mean that the user can't delete the records through the system they are using?  Or do you need something that will somehow keep the user from deleting the files that store the data?  Does the user have root/admin access to the machines this is installed on?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
1) Its a normal PC. Yes, its a DB driven app. Infrastructure is just what a normal commodity PC would have. OS will be mostly Windows. Platform is what I am trying to explore. On the basis of the platform, location of data-storage will change. 2) by strong security, i mean, the user cannot delete the data he/she just entered. user may or may-not of the root access to the machine. But we can restrict his access within our application. Does that give you enough stuff for answering the question?

Comment: Yes, but if the user has root access, it is almost impossible to prevent them from deleting the data.  The best you could really do is to send the data to some encrypted file, maybe obfuscate it somehow, and then prevent them from selectively deleting data.  They would still be able to wipe all the content.  If you were really concerned, add a second file for a checksum, and every time you write to the encrypted file, write to the checksum as well.  When the user connects to the server, send the checksum, and if it doesn't match the file, you at least know a file change has been made.

Comment: unless of course they are smart enough to backup the checksum from the last push...

Comment: That's great. Lets say, user doesn't have root access. Is there a way by which I can change permissions/ACLs at windows level, such that the user cannot directly modify the files and can only change the those files (i.e. enter or delete data) via our application.

Comment: You would have to run the file updating application as a separate service, which runs under a different username.  It's probably wise to have a separate service anyway, one that can regularly ping the central service so that it can do an upload when the internet connection comes back up.  That way you don't have to wait for the user to run the application, and if the connection comes up, it will send the data back home whether the front-end app is running or not.

Comment: You might want to look at what RDMS you are using.  Many of them have embedded versions available that you could include.  And they definitely will have rights models like "write only".  If you are exclusively running Windows, SQL Server Express is a nice cheap option:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

Comment: I want to target other OSes as well. Therefore, its not only Windows. Can that Embedded RDBMS be MySQL? And will ACLs stuff work fine in an embedded database?